# Prevent Jacoco from running in default gradle task (which happens on every local build)

Tags: android, gradle, jacoco

We have Jacoco running, but have noticed that Jacoco runs in the normal Android Studio build (such as pressing "Run" to deploy changes). This adds an unnecessary amount of time into the build time. I would rather only run Jacoco on demand (by an explicit gradle task) rather than have it included in every Android Studio build.

[image]

jacoco.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco-android'

jacocoAndroidUnitTestReport {
    csv.enabled true
    html.enabled false
    xml.enabled false
}
```

app.gradle:

```
android {
 testOptions {
        animationsDisabled true
        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
        }
        unitTests.all {
            jvmArgs '-noverify'
            jacoco {
                includeNoLocationClasses = true
            }
        }
    }
}

apply from: "jacoco.gradle"
```

Answer (score 2):

this is coming from `apply plugin: 'jacoco-android'` ...it's not the default behavior.

if you'd define the task in `jacoco.gradle`, this should not happen, unless explicitly running the task.

or you could try do disable the generation of the task (possibly this has to be per flavor `dev`):

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sweet I'll give this a try. Thanks!

Comment: How is it different? Because I will have to include jacoco.gradle in my app.gradle anyway